# Derived Class Cannot refer to parent class

Tags: c#-3.0

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Father objFather = new Son(); //Ok compiles

        Son objSon1 =  new Father(); //Comile time error : Cannot implicitly convert type

        Son objSon = (Son)new Father();  //Run time error
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Father
{
    public void Read()
    {

    }

}

class Daughter:Father
{

}

class Son:Father
{

}
```

Can anybody Explain why it is? And what is happening in memory?

Comment: Maybe you want to read about some basic concepts of OOP like [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) before asking specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand inheritance.

Every `Daughter` and every `Son` is a `Father`. That's why you can safely assign both to a `Father` variable. A subclass can't remove attributes/methods only add them, that's why it's sure it's always working.

But when you have an instance of `Father` and want to assign it to a `Son` variable, you can't be sure that the instance is a `Son` and actually has all the properties needed. The `Father` instance could as well contain a `Daughter` which is not compatible to `Son`. That's why the compiler can't implicitly convert them but you as a programmer can explicitly do it.